# Are there any reference for error codes of Telegram Bot API?

Tags: telegram-bot

Sending message via a Telegram Bot API may be failed due to difference problems like not existing chat_id any more. Are there any reference for these errors?

Answer (score 2):

From [Telegram Bot Api documentation page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests):

> The response contains a JSON object, which always has a Boolean field ‘ok’ and may have an optional String field ‘description’ with a human-readable description of the result. If ‘ok’ equals true, the request was successful and the result of the query can be found in the ‘result’ field. In case of an unsuccessful request, ‘ok’ equals false and the error is explained in the ‘description’. An Integer ‘error_code’ field is also returned, but its contents are subject to change in the future.

Whenever you make a request check if it succeed so you are sure if a certain `chat_it` is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Unofficial [Telegram wiki](https://telegram.wiki/bots/bot-error-codes) has some details on possible errors.

Comment: Access to this wiki is password protected.